# Add tooltip on vertex and show a label of vertex at the same time

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

Is it possible to have multiple labels appear on one vertex?

Let's say I want to show numbers on vertex always, and when I hover over a vertex, I want label to appear as tooltip. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

```
tencities = Take[EntityList[EntityClass["City", "UnitedStatesCapitals"]], 10];

names = #["Name"] & /@ tencities
```

> ```
>  {"Montgomery", "Juneau", "Phoenix", "Little Rock", "Sacramento",
> "Denver", "Hartford", "Dover", "Tallahassee", "Atlanta"}
> ```

```
pops = QuantityMagnitude[#@"Population"] & /@ tencities
```

> ```
>  {199518, 32094, 1626078, 198606, 501901, 704621, 123400, 37538, 191049, 486290}
> ```

```
labelingAssoc = AssociationThread[names, 
   Placed[{Last@#, Framed[#2, Background -> White]},
       {Tooltip, Center}] & @@@ Transpose[{tencities, pops}]];

SeedRandom[1]
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ RandomSample[Subsets[names, {2}], 15];


Graph[names, edges, ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> {v_ :> labelingAssoc[v]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
edges = {"A" -> "B", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "A"};
vertices = VertexList @ edges;

Graph[edges, VertexSize -> .07, 
 VertexLabels ->  MapIndexed[# -> Placed[Tooltip[#, #2[[1]]], Center] &, vertices]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Graph[edges, VertexSize -> .07, 
 VertexLabels -> MapIndexed[# -> Placed[{#, #2[[1]]}, {Center, Tooltip}] &, vertices]]
```

> same picture

Also

```
g0 = Graph[edges];
SetProperty[g0, {VertexSize -> .07, 
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[{v, VertexIndex[g0, v]}, {Center, Tooltip}]}}]
```

> same picture

Comment: This is close, but I want to put some other numbers (I have a list of them) instead of vertex index. I have a list of cities and each has a different number value "connected" to it, and I want to show numbers instead of A, B, C, and the tooltip should contain name of the city.

Comment: @me995, please see the update.